# Binding Tag property of checkbox to ancestor datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I know this is a frequently question but after viewing lots of question in this context i still did not find working solution.

I have this MainWindow

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Camera> Cameras { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Camera>();
    public ObservableCollection<Group> Groups { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Group>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

And this class

```
public class Group : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _number;
    [XmlAttribute("Number")]
    public int Number
    {
        get { return _number; }
        set
        {
            _number = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

This is part of the MainWindow.xaml (the relevant part)

```
<StackPanel>

    <Button Click="Button_Click_1" Margin="55,0,0,0" Padding="4">Add Group</Button>
    <ListView Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Margin="3" Width="30" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Number}"></TextBlock>
                    <ComboBox Margin="3" Width="50" Grid.Column="5" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Cameras, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}">
                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <CheckBox Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.Number}" Checked="OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked" Unchecked="OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked" />
                                    <!--<CheckBox Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tag="{Binding Path=DataContext.Number, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" Checked="OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked" Unchecked="OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked" />-->
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ComboBox>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    
    
</StackPanel>
```

The list of checkbox inside the comboxbox will be filled according to the list of the cameras.
I want to bind the property "Tag" of the inner checkbox to the member Groups.Number like i did with the textblock above it.
The reason behind this (maybe you have another solution) is that the list of groups is a dynamic group, and i want to identify from which group the checkbox was checked.
I've tried everything with the ancestor issue but nothing seems to work.
other things i've tried are:

```
                                        <CheckBox Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.Number}" Checked="OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked" Unchecked="OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked" />
                                    <CheckBox Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.Groups.Number}" Checked="OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked" Unchecked="OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked" />
                                    <CheckBox Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=Number}" Checked="OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked" Unchecked="OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked" />
                                    <CheckBox Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=Groups.Number}" Checked="OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked" Unchecked="OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked" />
```

What do i miss here?
Ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView` has the wron `DataContext`. It is outside the `DataTemplate` and is set to `MainWindow`. The `DataTemplate` that targets `Group` has the proper `DataContext`, of course the current `Group` item. You must chose an element of this `DataTemplate` as binding source. You couls bind to the `ComboBox.DataContext`:

```
<CheckBox Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}, Path=DataContext.Number}" />
```

Comment: ty, working in runtime. but now i get an error of: "Value cannot be null, Parameter name: node". even tough its an error i can still run the program

Comment: It seems like the error is related to something else. Where do you get this error? Where is the parameter `node`? Make sure it is initialized.